# Map function stores the value of the last object in the array to all values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting data from Firestore and using the map function to display all of that data. I am sending one of the arguments within a URL to get an image. I am sending a cryptocurrency pair in a URL to get an image in response. I am also displaying the pair in the table. However, when I send the same symbol in the map function, all of my pairs get the same pair sent in the url, the last pair of the data.
To simplify the issue:

**Steps:**

1. Map function to display data
2. `Pair` attribute is sent in the link to get image with every map function (click button to see image)
3. `Pair` function also displayed in the table

**Result:**

1. The pair in the table is unique and displaying correctly
2. All urls in the map function get the same pair, the pair of the last object.

```
 {data.map((trade) => (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <img
            src={trade.image}
            style={{
              width: "30px",
              height: "30px",
              marginTop: "13px",
              marginRight: "5px",
            }}
            alt="btc"
          />
          <p className="coin-name">{trade.symbol.baseAsset}</p>
        </div>
      </td>

{/* This same attribute is getting unique values and it is within the same map function */}
{/* ---------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------------------------------------- */}
      <td>{trade.symbol.symbol}</td>
      <td>{trade.qty}</td>

      <td>{Math.round(trade.multiplier)}x avg volume</td>

      <td>{trade.price}</td>
      <td>{trade.exchangeDetails.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
      <td>{Math.round(trade.tradeValue * 1000) / 1000}</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <Button
            onClick={handleOpen}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#142F37 ", color: "white" }}
          >
            View Graph
          </Button>
          <Modal
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
          >
            <Box sx={style}>
              <img
// This attribute is getting the same pair in every object
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                src={`https://2zpbbz.chart-img.com/v1/tradingview/advanced-chart?symbol=${trade.symbol.symbol}`}
                alt="No graph for this pair"
                style={{ width: "500px" }}
              />
            </Box>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

[image: UI]

Comment: Post code as text, not as image.

Comment: Added the code too

Answer (score 1):

Making the modal as a different component and passing URL as a prop to that component did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add return statement after your `.map` and move your your url outside and save it in a variable

```
data.map((trade, i)=>{
  let symbol = trade.symbol.symbol;
  let url = 'https://...'+ symbol;
  return(
    <tr>
     ...
    </tr>
  )

}
```

and then pass in the url created to src of the `<img src={url} ... />`

Comment: This did not work. Now it is storing 4th last in every url

Comment: I console logged the url, all urls are unique (as required) but the images are still not being loaded properly as they should be

Comment: pass the`i` as key to the the tr to make it unique `<tr key={i}> ...</tr>`